# How can I return a generic list generated by a query to a DataGrid ItemSource?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm

I am generating a DataGrid from an Entity Model, which was very simple in the code behind. But now that I am trying to bind it in an MVVM pattern, I can't seem to figure out how to return a generic list.

From the ModelView:

```
    public ??? LoadMoviesMethod()
    {
        ObjectQuery<MovieTable> _movies = dataEntities.MovieTables;

        var query =
            from MovieTable in _movies
            where MovieTable.Rating == "R"
            orderby MovieTable.id
            select new { MovieTable.Title, MovieTable.Rating, MovieTable.Stars, MovieTable.ReleaseYear };

       ??? MoviesList = query.ToList();
       return MoviesList;

//where as the code behind was simply gridName.ItemsSource = query.ToList()

    }
```

Sending into the DataGrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MovieMockup.MovieMockupListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" 
         d:DesignWidth="300">
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding MovieMockupListModel.MoviesList}">

</DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `IList` or `IEnumerable`, although I suppose you could also return `object`